# Newbie has difficulty compiling unedited svn Arduino code that should work

Tags: c++

I'm having some trouble getting this arduino code to compile. It's not my project, but it should compile totally fine. Having never worked with the Arduino before, these errors are a bit intimidating, but I'll try to be specific enough for someone to get a guess. So...

I have this directory with these files: [image: here] .

I found that the ArduCAM_OSD.ino has the loop and setup functions. When I try to compile the ino and solution I get these errors:

```
In file included from ArduCam_Max7456.cpp:4:

ArduCam_Max7456.h:78: error: expected class-name before '{' token

ArduCam_Max7456.h:84: error: 'uint8_t' has not been declared

ArduCam_Max7456.h:84: error: 'uint8_t' has not been declared

ArduCam_Max7456.h:87: error: 'uint8_t' has not been declared

ArduCam_Max7456.h:91: error: 'uint8_t' has not been declared

ArduCam_Max7456.h:91: error: 'uint8_t' has not been declared

ArduCam_Max7456.h:98: error: 'size_t' does not name a type

ArduCam_Max7456.h:99: error: 'uint8_t' has not been declared

ArduCam_Max7456.h:100: error: 'BetterStream' has not been declared

ArduCam_Max7456.h:102: error: 'uint8_t' does not name a type

ArduCam_Max7456.cpp: In member function 'void OSD::init()':

ArduCam_Max7456.cpp:38: error: 'video_mode' was not declared in this scope

ArduCam_Max7456.cpp: In member function 'void OSD::setMode(int)':

ArduCam_Max7456.cpp:109: error: 'video_mode' was not declared in this scope

ArduCam_Max7456.cpp:110: error: 'video_center' was not declared in this scope

ArduCam_Max7456.cpp: In member function 'int OSD::getMode()':

ArduCam_Max7456.cpp:123: error: 'video_mode' was not declared in this scope

ArduCam_Max7456.cpp: In member function 'int OSD::getCenter()':

ArduCam_Max7456.cpp:138: error: 'video_center' was not declared in this scope

ArduCam_Max7456.cpp: At global scope:

ArduCam_Max7456.cpp:162: error: prototype for 'void OSD::setPanel(uint8_t, uint8_t)' does 
not match any in class 'OSD'

ArduCam_Max7456.h:84: error: candidate is: void OSD::setPanel(int, int)

ArduCam_Max7456.cpp: In member function 'void OSD::openPanel()':

ArduCam_Max7456.cpp:177: error: 'row' was not declared in this scope

ArduCam_Max7456.cpp:177: error: 'col' was not declared in this scope

ArduCam_Max7456.cpp: In member function 'void OSD::closePanel()':

ArduCam_Max7456.cpp:206: error: 'row' was not declared in this scope

ArduCam_Max7456.cpp: At global scope:

ArduCam_Max7456.cpp:212: error: prototype for 'void OSD::openSingle(uint8_t, uint8_t)' does 
not match any in class 'OSD'

ArduCam_Max7456.h:91: error: candidate is: void OSD::openSingle(int, int)


ArduCam_Max7456.cpp:236: error: no 'size_t OSD::write(uint8_t)' member function declared in 
class 'OSD'

ArduCam_Max7456.cpp:251: error: prototype for 'void OSD::control(uint8_t)' does not match 
any in class 'OSD'

ArduCam_Max7456.h:87: error: candidate is: void OSD::control(int)

ArduCam_Max7456.cpp:268: error: prototype for 'void OSD::write_NVM(int, uint8_t*)' does not 
match any in class 'OSD'

ArduCam_Max7456.h:99: error: candidate is: void OSD::write_NVM(int, int*)
```

The most notable of these is the first error. Here's the class, in a header file, throwing the error:

```
class OSD: public BetterStream
{
  public:
    OSD(void);
    void init(void);
    void clear(void);
    void plug(void);
    void setPanel(uint8_t start_col, uint8_t start_row);
    void openPanel(void);
    void closePanel(void);
    void control(uint8_t ctrl);
    void detectMode(void);
    void setMode(int mode);
    void setBrightness();
    void openSingle(uint8_t x, uint8_t y);
    int getMode(void);
    int getCenter(void);
    virtual int     available(void);
    virtual int     read(void);
    virtual int     peek(void);
    virtual void    flush(void);
    virtual size_t write(uint8_t c);
    void write_NVM(int font_count, uint8_t *character_bitmap);
    using BetterStream::write;
  private:
    uint8_t start_col, start_row, col, row, video_mode, video_center;
};
```

Now, since I know confidently that this should compile, I'm convinced that I've made some 
small syntactical error that can be fixed easily. In case anyone needs to see more of the files, you can access them all on the google code page [here](http://arducam-osd.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ArduCAM_OSD/). Alternatively, please feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Is it your own code? I guess you have not properly imported the complete project. This is just a class. where are other files? the main? Or may be you have not properly installed the compiler of this IDE. Which IDE is this?

Comment: is it your complete class? you have not included  ´BetterStream` and you are inheriting it.

Comment: add #include<BetterStream> before the class definition

Comment: @Mahmood I'm using Arduino IDE 1.0.5-r2 . It's not my own code. All of the code is at the link at the bottom,  though I'll look for a main. I believe I was told to look for setup and loop to determine the ino to compile, which is in ArduCAM_OSD.ino .

Comment: add #include"BetterStream" if it works. tell me

Comment: @Mahmood adding "#include "BetterStream.h" did work to get rid of all those errors after I went and found a copy of BetterStream.h. Thanks!

Comment: @Mahmood I only have one more error. One of my include statements is failing, even though the file is indeed in the same directory. Another file is referenced the same exact way, yet it can't see this one particular file.

Comment: which file? name the file I will see

Comment: #include "menu.h"
    #include "c++.h"

In file included from AP_Common.cpp:16:
/AP_Common.h:38:35: error: c++.h: No such file or directory

What's weird is that menu.h and c++.h exist in the same location, yet menu is included fine.

Comment: I guess you are missing some files in the library of your installation of IDE. Because these files seems to be libraries. Does you ide works perfectly? Is it your first program you are testing? try something other working one.

Comment: @Mahmood I found that the issue was that I wasn't using the IDE to include all the libraries so it wasn't seeing any of the references. After including all of the relevant libraries I finally got it to compile. Thanks so much!

Comment: This is really ambitious for a first project. Do yourself a favor and go through the basic tutorials before you start frying components. Learning how to include libraries properly is something you will pick up if you go through the basics. Arduino isn't "safe" - it's easy to fry the Arduino and easy to melt components too.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are missing the libraries that the project was build for. BetterStream was part of the library system of the Ardu projects at diydrones.com

Normally for Ardu projects they use a modified version (their own) of the Arduino IDE but I don't know if the Arducam project works the same way.

I think you will find a better answer over in the support forum as http://www.diydrones.com which is where Arducam comes from.

Some of the source files look like they replace libraries so it might be that you just need a different core from diyd